# Git cherry-picking includes changes from previous commit

Tags: git

I'm working on a project with repository `repo` which has an upstream `upstream`. I've made some changes to a branch `feature` in `upstream` and now I want to apply the same changes in my local clone of `repo`.

I followed [instructions](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/working-with-forks/configuring-a-remote-repository-for-a-fork) to set `upstream` as a remote and then cherry-picked 2 commits with the range syntax `A^..B`. My expectation is that this should only include the changes I made in those 2 commits. However, somehow Git decided to include a previous change that I did not make as well.

Can someone help me explain why this happens and what alternatives are there?

Comment: Was it a conflict?

Comment: @ElpieKay Yes, was a small one

Comment: It's only 2 commits? Are `A` and `B` one after the other? Cause if they are not, then that won't give you 2 commits to cherry-pick.

Comment: @linhns with a conflict, the unexpected changes are as normal as designed. The changes you want are dependent on these lines. You didn't apply them in the first place as intended, and it caused the conflict. When resolving the conflict, 
 just remove them if you really don't want them.

Comment: @eftshift0 Yes they're two commits.

Comment: @ElpieKay Understood. I've been browsing docs on git snapshot and fully understand why it happens now. At every commit if a file is not modifed, a pointer to the last change is stored.